# $AA^T =A$, what can you say about the rank of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

$AA^T =A$, what can you say about the rank of $A$?

---

Interview question, and I have no idea. The closest thing I can relate to is the inverse. But that's not the case here.

Comment: I remember seeing something like this in the PCA lecturers. But I can’t recall the details extactly

Comment: The identity matrix works.

Comment: As does any diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $0$'s and $1$'s.  So the rank can be anything from $0$ to $n$ (for $n \times n$ matrices).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Robert Israel has already given the answer to the question asked—the rank can be any nonnegative integer up to the dimension of the matrix. However I wanted to point out that one can say a lot more: note that
$$
A^T = (AA^T)^T = (A^T)^TA^T = AA^T = A,
$$
and so $A$ symmetric. In particular, we now know that $A^2=A$ and so $A^2-A=0$, which means that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $t^2-t$. This tells a lot about the matrix $A$ (that it's diagonalizable and that its eiegnvalues can only be $0$ or $1$), and ultimately says that it is a projection matrix.